# Threading with ExecutorService-java

Tags: java, multithreading

As you can see, i have two classes WorkerThread and ThreadPool. I am trying to execute workerthread task after a initial delay of 3 seconds and then the same task after the delay of another 3 seconds. I used both schedulewithfixedelay  & scheduleAtfixedRate and it waits for the first time but not the second time. I am new to high-level thread programming so can anyone help me with what i am doing wrong in the following code or is there any alternative classes to achieve the task.

```
class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private String command;

    public WorkerThread(String s){
        this.command=s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Start. Command = "+command);
        processCommand();
        try {
            System.out.println("Doing a task during : " + command + " - Time - " + new Date());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" End.");
    }

    private void processCommand() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.command;
    }
}


  public class ThreadPool {
      public static int times=0;
 public static ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        WorkerThread worker = new WorkerThread("proud"); 
       int i=0;
        while(i<2)
        {
        System.out.println(i);

        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(worker, 3, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        i++;
        }
```

Output:

```
pool-1-thread-2 Start. Command = proud//waits for 3 seconds
pool-1-thread-1 Start. Command = proud//does not wait (for 3 seconds) to execute the same task 
Doing a task during : proud - Time - Sat Nov 21 18:10:56 EST 2015
pool-1-thread-1 End.
Doing a task during : proud - Time - Sat Nov 21 18:10:56 EST 2015
pool-1-thread-2 End.
```

Comment: Read through the documentation of both, but knowing what the code in your job does, do you want `scheduleAtFixedRate` or `scheduleAtFixedDelay`?

Comment: I read them and so i used(correct me if i am wrong).I think my problem is not what i should be using but both behaves almost the same in the above code. I want to execute the same task with a fixed periodic delay which is not achievable in my case.

Comment: Could you explain what you're expecting to see and what you're actually seeing?

Comment: i added the output. I  want the task to be executed the second time after a delay of 3 seconds (with the thread that is available in the pool)

Comment: Since you scheduled the task twice and have two threads in the pool, both will wail for three seconds, then run at almost the exact same time. Do you really want to schedule the same task to be run at similar times in parallel? I'm not sure you really want to be calling `schedule...` twice.

Comment: No i want the same task to run with a delay of 3 seconds.

Comment: I tried calling it once but it is sequential rather parallel.

Comment: That's the documented behavior: *If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.*. I'll rephrase David's question: Do you really want the task to start re-executing while the previous execution has not finished yet? If so, each task should probably only consist in submitting its job to an ExecutorService.

Comment: @JB Nizet Does ExecutorService provide delay guarantee? I do not think so. The problem is i do not want to put threads to sleep in the while loop.

Comment: What I mean is that you should use a ScheduledExecutorService to schedule your tasks. But these tasks should simply consist in submitting the actual WorkerThread commands to another ExecutorService, to be executed immediately, so that a second WorkerThread can start executing even if the first one hasn't finished yet.